# PDO ATTR_PERSISTENT -> true with SQLSRV causing delays / fails

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

I am wondering if anyone is having difficulties using the PDO ATTR_PERSISTENT set to TRUE option for the SQLSRV driver.

When I have this enabled one of three things will randomly happen:

- On page load it will be instant and no problems.
- On page load it will take 1-5 seconds to load but no other problems.
- On page load 404 will appear.

I read that a persistent DB connection is recommended. Maybe I should ditch it?

```
//Setup PDO DNS.
$pdo_DNS = "sqlsrv:Server=" . $this->db_Host . ";Database=" . $this->db_Name;

//Setup PDO Options.
$pdo_Options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Establish DB Connection.
try
{
  $this->pdo_DB = new PDO($pdo_DNS, $this->db_User, $this->db_Pass, $pdo_Options);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $this->db_Error->create($e, "__construct", PAL_ERR_CONNECT);
}
```

Comment: A 404 page? You're having more issues than you may think...Have you tried benchmarking the `new PDO();` call?

Comment: The instant I remove ATTR_PERSISTENT => from the PDO options I have absolutely zero issues and every page load is instant and never fails. How can I benchmark my PDO call with ATTR_PERSISTENT enabled?

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*." "Well, stop doing that."

Comment: In general a persistent connection is more expensive upon initial connect and every connect there-after, on the same child thread, is super quick. How many users are using this system at any given time? In your `try{}` block place `$start = microtime(true);` before calling PDO and then `echo (microtime(true) - $start).' seconds';` after the PDO call.

Comment: The 404 is likely an issue of error reporting - you're probably getting a warning saying PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT is in invalid attribute to use with PDO_SQLSRV, which uses connection pooling instead of persistent connections.